# How to force chrome display a Save As Dialog when i click a download link?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm using WebKitBlobBuilder in chrome to generate a text file in user side.

Now, i need to show a save as dialog, let user decide which folder to put the newly generated file.(In chrome)

"Save As Dialog", no browser configurations.

How? Thanks!

Comment: This title is misleading. You should revise.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible since Chrome has an option in the Preferences pane to `Ask where to save each file before downloading` which someone could simply uncheck... You might try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009789/force-save-as-box-in-chrome-safari-when-clicking-on-a-data-uri-anchor-link

Comment: You cann't specify a filename with Data URI :(

Comment: You can trigger a click on a link that has a download attribute. Example: `<a href="item.txt" download>`

Comment: Not  sure why this thread was closed fir that reason, it could not be more clear what he is asking!

Answer (score 11):

Check the Settings --> Show Advanced Settings --> Downloads section.
Tick the "Ask where to save each file before downloading" option. And try!

Comment: He mentioned that he needs a solution without changing the browser settings, since it is for the users and not for him personally.